# how to verify app engine site that use oauth2 login

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-console

How to verify my app engine site (e.g. sitename-dot-appname.appspot.com) that use oauth2 login using google webmaster tools? I already tried using html file, but it's always failed.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site use Oauth2, you must have some business logic code to check user privileges, and so you should be able to add a rule that bypass oauth2 to serve the webmaster tools html verification file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Even if I remove oauth2, it's still redirect to the google login page. Can you give me a simple example of bypass this google login page? thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have any [login property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status) in app engine configuration?

Comment: I tried to disable it by removing the <security-constraint> to the backend servlet for path /_ah/start. But it still doesn't work. It always redirect to this link https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?...

Comment: Can you please edit your question with relevant parts of appengine-web.xml?

Comment: I get my answer to change my web.xml <security-constraint> for url-pattern. I didn't know that * means you need user to sign in first and before my <url-pattern> use /* with role of *. Thanks for your answer.